# Use common library for several package inside same repository

Tags: go

I'm working on a project where I store several go lambda in the same repository with this architecture:

```
GOPATH/
  src/
   github.com/my-user/my-project
     lambda1/
     lambda2/
     lambda3/
     library/
```

my-project is not a go project and contain other informations ( conf files, ...), each repository is an "independant" go project with its own main package and main.go

What I want is to create a common library (folder library) to share some struct or common methods to all the lambda.

But I didn't found anyway to import the library into my lambda directories ( without having to create a new git repository/project)

I tried different imports like

```
import "github.com/my-user/my-project/library"
import "my-project/library"
```

but nothing works

my library project follow this architecture:

```
library
  one-model-package/
  another-model-package/
  go.mod
```

without main.go or main package

the go.mod for the library repo is:

```
module library

go 1.14
```

Have I made some mistake in the library declaration or import ? Or do I have to use external repository ?

Answer (score 1):

First, when using modules your code should probably not be stored in `$GOPATH/src` as that itself might cause problems:

> As of Go 1.11, the go command enables the use of modules when the current directory or any parent directory has a go.mod, provided the directory is outside `$GOPATH/src`. (Inside `$GOPATH/src`, for compatibility, the go command still runs in the old `GOPATH` mode, even if a `go.mod` is found.

To have multiple modules inside single repository I believe you still need top-level `go.mod` file initialized as `go mod init github.com/my-user/my-project` and then `library` directory that has its own module file needs to be initialized with `go mod init ./library`. Then `import "github.com/my-user/my-project/library"` should work. See [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27056) as reference. There still might be some issues with `go mod replace` and interdependent submodules (e.g. if your `lambda1` depends on `library`).

See more about how modules and their naming works [here](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules).

Comment: the go.mod is the one in the library/ directory.
the main directory my-project is not a part of any go package as every repositories are independant

Comment: Oh that was not clear from the question. Then AFAIK your module name in that file should be `./library` and you should have top-level `go.mod` file initialized as above in my reply. You can do `go mod edit -replace library=./library` inside `library` subdirectory.

Comment: Updated my answer.